# Using a webcam with flask

Tags: opencv, flask, ip, webcam

I am doing web development with flask.
I want to turn on the web camera as in video conferencing regardless of the operating system.

I am using cv2.VideoCapture(0) with opencv on the server. This means that when another laptop connects to the server's IP, the laptop's webcam is not turned on, but the server's webcam is turned on.

cv2.VideoCapture('http://IP:PORT/video0'), cv2.VideoCapture('http://IP:PORT/0'), cv2.VideoCapture('IP:PORT/0') does not work.

Help Please..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your answer to specify what exactly went wrong? Is there an error message that you could share? Including your code would also help. Thanks!